# How to search string smart in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a example:

```
Good Bye
Hello World 
Bye Morning
```

INPUT:

```
Good Mor
```

OUTPUT:

```
Good Bye
Bye Morning
```

Have in mysql function search with this keyword ? LIKE, MATCH, how ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [MySql Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

Full-text searching is somewhat akin to a LIKE condition, but is much faster, requiring a FULLTEXT index to be created for the table columns targeted in the search. To search the title and description columns of a table, entries, the following statement would create the proper index

Something like below:

```
 SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE MATCH (content)
 AGAINST ('Good Mor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> inputstring =%+input+%;
>   
> SELECT word FROM word_table WHERE word LIKE '"+inputstring+"'";